# jQuery .val() method giving me the first entered value only

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the jQuery UI Dialog box to enter the URL of the Image. I am using the following method:

```
 <input id="dlg" value="Open Dialog" type="button" />

<script type="text/javascript">
var img = '<div id="dialog" title="Insert Image" style="width:500px;height:300px">';
img += '<table><tr><td style="width:100px">';
img += 'Image URL: </td><td><input id="txt" type="text" value="" size="52" /></td>';
img += '</tr></table></div>';

$('#dlg').click(function(){

$(img).dialog({buttons: {'Ok':function(){
    var value = $("#txt").val();
    var http = value.substr(0,7);

    alert(value);

    $(this).dialog('close');
}}},

 { closeOnEscape:true, resizable:false, width:600, height:200

 });


});
</script>
```

When I Press the `(<input id="dlg" value="Open Dialog" type="button" />)` button a dialog box appears, with a textbox input field. When I enter any value in the text field, It alerts that value. But when I Press the Button Second or Third time and Enter some other value in the textbox of the dialog, and press OK, it alerts the value that I entered for the first time. So, No matter How many times I click the button and enter any value, it will alert the value that I entered first time.

Am I getting the text box value `var value = $("#txt").val();` correctly with this method?
If Yes, then Why it is giving me the first time entered value.

Note: I have cleared the cache of my browser so many times, so there is no chance of any cache problem.

Comment: That's because you're creating multiple dialogs and never destroying or removing them, so you're getting duplicate ID's with your input and you always get the first one. You need to properly clean up the dialog in the onclose, or stop re-creating the dialog with each button click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is each time you call it you are making a new copy of the dialog. That means you have multiple elements with the same name. To avoid that you need to destroy the dialog after you close it.

Change:

```
$(this).dialog('close');
```

To

```
$(this).dialog('close').dialog("destroy");
```

Other option is to create the element once and than reuse it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the txt items are being created multiple times.  You would need to remove the item from the DOM once you are done.

in this section

```
$(img).dialog({buttons: {'Ok':function(){
    var value = $("#txt").val();
    var http = value.substr(0,7);

    alert(value);

    // save value somewhere

    $("#txt").remove();

    $(this).dialog('close');
}}},
```

Comment: lol, nevermind I like @epascarello answer better.  Its far cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are creating the dom structure every time the dialog is created, so it is fetching the first created input box every time you request `$("#txt")`.

So the solution is to remove the complete dom structure on close of the widget

```
$(img).dialog({
    buttons: {
        'Ok':function(){
            var value = $("#txt").val();
            var http = value.substr(0,7);

            alert(value);

            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    },
    close: function(){
        $(this).remove()
    },

    closeOnEscape:true, 
    resizable:false, 
    width:600, 
    height:200
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

> No matter How many times I click the button and enter any value, it will alert the value that I entered first time.
>
> Am I getting the text box value `var value = $("#txt").val();` correctly with this method?

Yes.

> If Yes, then Why it is giving me the first time entered value.

Because `$("#txt")` refers to the first element in the DOM with that id. On each click, you dynamically create elements from your `img` string and append them to the DOM via the `dialog` widget. Yet, calling its `close` method only hides them, but does not remove them from the DOM so the click handler always extracts its `value` from the first created input.

Try calling the [`destroy` method](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-destroy) instead:

```
$(this).dialog('close').dialog("destroy"); // not sure whether the "close" is still necessary
```

Or you create the dialog only once, and `open` it on every click.